# Can't run pm2 process with Port 80

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a Node project that needs to run under port 80, but am having issues running the pm2 project with Port 80, the instances of my app run but I get the same predictable issues with EACCESS on Port 80

```
Error: bind EACCES null:80
  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
  at cb (net.js:1302:16)
  at rr (cluster.js:594:14)
  at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:564:9)
  at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:714:8)
  at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
  at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
  at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:689:10)
  at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
```

I did some research and tried [the setcap approach](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) outlined here, only to run into issues giving node those rights (probably because I made `node` a symlink to `nodejs`, which is set to run at port 80):

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/bin/node' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

I've tried to run the pm2 instance as sudo, with no success. The process refuses to connect on port 80. Is there an easier way to go about this? Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: what error do you get with sudo?

Comment: It actually works with port 80 when run on sudo. So I guess question answered. Not sure why it wasn't before.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot listen on a port number under 1024 without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

This article was copied form PM2 documentation 
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/

It’s a general rule that you should not run node as root. However only root can bind to ports less than 1024. This is where authbind comes in. Authbind allows non-root users to bind to ports less than 1024. Replace %user% with the user that will be running pm2.

sudo apt-get install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
You should also add an alias to the user that runs pm2 profile, e.g. ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc (note you will need to run source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.zshrc immediately after):

+alias pm2='authbind --deep pm2'
Finally ensure that pm2 is updated with authbind:

authbind --deep pm2 update
Or simply pm2 update if you added the alias to your user’s profile.

Now you can start applications using PM2 that can bind to port 80 without being root!